# Is there a symbol to say a random variable is not distributed according to a distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

$\sim$ (tilde)
means that a random variable is distributed according to a distribution.

but $\not\sim$ (not tilde)
is valid to say that a random variable is not distributed according to a distribution?

e.g.: $X ≁ N(μ,σ^2)$

to say that X is not distributed according to a normal distribution?

Comment: Seems good enough to me. I am not aware of a standard alternative

Comment: So $X\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ is not excluded ($\mu_1\ne \mu$)?

Comment: @d.k.o. it should means it isn't distributed like that.